# Parsing Complex JSON (Navigating the hierarchy of objects it produces) in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsmutablearray, sbjson

I am developing an app based on school menus and dishes where I am stuck is in parsing **complex/nested json**

Sample Json URL : [Json Data](http://private-e8e699-yumyummi.apiary-mock.com/districts/115/schools/43/menus/)

So far I have just done this as mentioned in below code using **SBJSON**:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {

    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
        [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];

    }

    else
    {

        Url =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://private-e8e699-yumyummi.apiary-mock.com/districts/115/schools/43/menus/"];
        checkData =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        URLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError  *error = nil;
        NSData  *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:URLRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        SBJsonParser* parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

        NSError *jsonError;
        if(jsonError == nil)
        {
            id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];


            NSLog(@"%@",json);

            NSDictionary *data = [json objectForKey:@"data"];            
    }
});
```

Comment: Well you seem to have done the parsing.  What you are stuck on, I expect, is navigating the hierarchy of objects it produces.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, could you be more clear about the issue you are facing in parsing / traversing this json object?

Comment: exactly @trojanfoe i am stuck in navigating the hierarchy of objects

Comment: Well that is fairly easy.  If it's an array then it's `array[index]` and if it's a dictionary it's `dict[@"keyname"]`.  Just be prepared for non-existent entries (don't make assumptions).

Comment: @trojanfoe, can u please help me with a sample code?

Comment: You'd need to show (a portion of) the JSON and what you want from it.

Comment: What particular data you want from the json file?

Comment: The scenario is, i will get a week data from server, then i have to display the data as per date provided by the user. I have 2 tabs breaky,lunchy. the data to be displayed are menus, dishes, sub_items for the respected tabs i.e. breaky, lunchy

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you don't know the exact structure of the data in your json, you can use something like:

```
if([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionnary class]) {
    // actions for a dictionnary
    id branch = json[@"your key"];
} else if([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]) {
    // actions for an array
    id branch = json[index];
}
```

Also the line `if(jsonError == nil)` make no sense, you sould do this after doing `[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];`